# Return forkJoin selectively

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a case where an application should `return menu based on given context`.

Below are the sources of `menuA` and `menuB`.

```
// example of menu derived from given source
  menuA() {
    return [
      {
        a: 'demo1',
        b: 'demo2',
        c: 'demo3'
      },
      {
        e: 'demo4',
        f: 'demo5',
        g: 'demo6'
      }
    ];
  }

  // example of menu fetched from different source eg: db
  async menuB() {
    const ret = [];
    const h = {
      a: 'demo1',
      b: 'demo2',
      c: 'demo3'
    };
    ret.push(h);
    return await ret;
  }
```

Given my limited knowledge and experience on `rxjs`, I was hoping something like the snippet below can accept a `string` of `menuA` or `menuB` to return an `observable` of the `required menu`:

```
getMenu$(context: string) {
    return forkJoin(
      {
        menuA: of(this.menuA()),
        menuB: from(this.menuB())
      }
    ).pipe(
      mergeMap((m: any) => {
        return m[context];
      })
    )
  }
```

The above invokes warning as below:

```
Argument of type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<{ menuA: ({ a: string; b: string; c: string; e?: undefined; f?: undefined; g?: undefined; } | { e: string; f: string; g: string; a?: undefined; b?: undefined; c?: undefined; })[]; menuB: { a: string; b: string; c: string; }[]; }, unknown>'.
  Type 'Observable<unknown>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<{ menuA: ({ a: string; b: string; c: string; e?: undefined; f?: undefined; g?: undefined; } | { e: string; f: string; g: string; a?: undefined; b?: undefined; c?: undefined; })[]; menuB: { a: string; b: string; c: string; }[]; }>): Observable<...>'.ts(2345)
The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<any>'.ts(2684)
```

Based on a comment below, I have also added the warning message when map is used to replace the mergeMap:

```
// modified getMenu$:
getMenu$(context: string) {
    return forkJoin(
      {
        menuA: of(this.menuA()),
        menuB: from(this.menuB())
      }
    ).pipe(
      map(m => m[context])
    )
  }
```

Warning message:

```
Argument of type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<{ menuA: ({ a: string; b: string; c: string; e?: undefined; f?: undefined; g?: undefined; } | { e: string; f: string; g: string; a?: undefined; b?: undefined; c?: undefined; })[]; menuB: { a: string; b: string; c: string; }[]; }, unknown>'.
  Type 'Observable<unknown>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<{ menuA: ({ a: string; b: string; c: string; e?: undefined; f?: undefined; g?: undefined; } | { e: string; f: string; g: string; a?: undefined; b?: undefined; c?: undefined; })[]; menuB: { a: string; b: string; c: string; }[]; }>): Observable<...>'.ts(2345)
The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<unknown>'.ts(2684)
```

I am using `angular 12` and `rxjs "~6.6.0"`.

Comment: replace the `mergeMap` with `map` operator to return the proper menu.

Comment: I'm not sure what is `return await ret;` supposed to do. `ret` is an array, but maybe it's just simplified example.

Comment: when I use map instead of mergeMap, I get simmilar warning: Argument of type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction

Comment: The return await ret was just a simple snippet to represent an async source of data. Otherwise the main area of interest is developing ability to return menu from different sources including Promise by selecting via a string context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ktm2hz?file=index.ts

```
function menuA() {
      return [
        {
          a: 'demo1',
          b: 'demo2',
          c: 'demo3'
        },
        {
          e: 'demo4',
          f: 'demo5',
          g: 'demo6'
        }
      ];
    }
    
    // example of menu fetched from different source eg: db
    function menuB() {
      return of([
        {
          a: 'demo1',
          b: 'demo2',
          c: 'demo3'
        }
      ]).pipe(delay(500));
    }
    
    function getMenu$(context: string) {
      return forkJoin(of(menuA()), menuB().pipe(first())).pipe(
        map(([menuA, menuB]) => ({ menuA, menuB })),
        map(m => m[context])
      );
    }
    getMenu$('menuA').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    getMenu$('menuB').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

you need to declare your menus.
I have created Enum for it

DEMO with Angular 12:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-template-wcgohi?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { forkJoin, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { first, map, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

enum Menus {
  menuA = 'menuA',
  menuB = 'menuB'
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  menuA(): { [key: string]: any }[] {
    return [
      {
        a: 'demo1',
        b: 'demo2',
        c: 'demo3'
      },
      {
        e: 'demo4',
        f: 'demo5',
        g: 'demo6'
      }
    ];
  }

  // example of menu fetched from different source eg: db
  menuB(): Observable<{ [key: string]: any }[]> {
    return of([
      {
        a: 'demo1',
        b: 'demo2',
        c: 'demo3'
      }
    ]).pipe(delay(500));
  }

  getMenu$(context: Menus): Observable<{ [key: string]: any }[]> {
    return forkJoin([of(this.menuA()), this.menuB().pipe(first())]).pipe(
      map(([menuA, menuB]) => ({ menuA, menuB })),
      map(m => m[context])
    );
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMenu$(Menus.menuA).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    this.getMenu$(Menus.menuB).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me test on my side and revert

Comment: The above work in stackblitz but raises warnings in vsc with angular 12. The first warning is given on delay(500): "Argument of type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<{ a: string; b: string; c: string; }[], unknown>'..."

Comment: ... the rest are spread around the getMenu$.  Including signature for forkJoin, then on first(), we have "Argument of type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, never>'..."

Comment: ...in short it is not compilable as is. I am hoping to get solutions on the type warning.  Let me know if you have suggestions.

Comment: Let me test on my side and revert

Comment: I am grateful for your above answer. It is working. I have also noted that the type issues I continue to have is on angular library project.  Interestingly on the same project, the warnings do not show on regular angular project.  Now trying to narrow down on that...suggestions are highly welcome.

Comment: because angular 12 is strictly type-safe